# How to properly make blocking service calls with Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, blocking, nonblocking, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am dealing with a http library (specifically one for making graphql calls) and it's API only offers blocking calls and is written in Java.

Now, I am writing my application with Kotlin and using the coroutines library, it got me wondering how should i make the blocking network call using coroutines.

So I have got this bit of code:

```
class DataService(val client: Client) {
    suspend fun getData(request: Request) {
        // process request

        client.makeServiceCall(...)

        //deal with response
    }
}

class Client() {
    suspend fun makeServiceCall(...) {
        library.query(....) //make a network call using the above mentioned library
    }
}
```

so I am wondering if `Client.makeServiceCall()` should be actually be marked as a suspending function because it does not actually suspend, it only blocks when it makes the network call. And how should i be making the call from `DataService.getData()` to `makeServiceCall()` and still adhere to the structured concurrency principles (like parent-child coroutine relationship)?

Answer (score 5):

Because the api you are using makes blocking calls doesn't necessarily mean that you need to adhere to that.  If you are already using Kotlin coroutines you can easily use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO` to require a function to run on an IO thread.  You absolutely should do this to avoid hanging the UI thread.

```
    suspend fun makeServiceCall(...) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // This code now executes on a background thread and will not block the UI
        library.query(....) //make a network call using the above mentioned library
    }
```

Comment: this is actually on a kotlin spring boot backend application, so there is no UI thread but i appreciate I should still be running the service call on a different thread i guess. Is there any advantage of using withContext over async and then await on the result. I seem to not be able to make async call directly - it needs a coroutine scope i believe

Comment: Difference between `withContext` and launch/async is that former doesn't create a new coroutine, but just switches the context. But you still need to call your `getData` function from within coroutine - launch { getData() }, and for that you need a coroutine scope.

Answer (score 2):

Use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` in your `makeServiceCall` function